# How to run coverage.py in json mode on a module?

Tags: code-coverage, coverage.py

I find coverage.py's CLI syntax to be overengineered: it would all be simpler if options on the format such as json or xml were specified as options instead of separate commands (which often have analogous options with completely different names compared to `coverage run`).

In particular, when I run `coverage` normally I do `coverage run -m pytest` to run `pytest`. If I want the report to be in JSON format however, the `-m` option is not available (`coverage json -m pytest`):

> no such option: -m

But of course, `coverage json pytest` also doesn't work:

> No source for code: '[redacted]\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytest': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '[redacted]\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytest'

So how am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it would all be simpler if options on the format such as json or xml were specified as options instead of separate commands

You know that there are separate commands, you have to use them as separate commands:

```
coverage run -m pytest
coverage json
```

Running code and measuring it is one step, which writes a data file.  Then you generate a report from that file with another command.

Comment: Oh that wasn't clear at all to me. Makes sense now, thank you.